# Understanding pointer to a vector of pointers code

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, struct, malloc

(I didn't write this code. This is an existing piece of code from UC Berkeley's parallel algorithms homework which I should parallelize using Pthreads)
There is this piece of code in my Parallel Algorithms homework's `int main()` function:

```
particle_t *particles = (particle_t*) malloc( n * sizeof(particle_t) );
init_particles( n, particles );
vector<particle_t*> *bins = new vector<particle_t*>[numbins];
```

with `particle_t` being defined outside of the `int main()` as:

```
typedef struct 
{
  double x;
  double y;
  double vx;
  double vy;
  double ax;
  double ay;
} particle_t;
```

and `init_partciles()` as :

```
void init_particles( int n, particle_t *p )
{
    srand48( time( NULL ) );
        
    int sx = (int)ceil(sqrt((double)n));
    int sy = (n+sx-1)/sx;
    
    int *shuffle = (int*)malloc( n * sizeof(int) );
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        shuffle[i] = i;
    
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        //
        //  make sure particles are not spatially sorted
        //
        int j = lrand48()%(n-i);
        int k = shuffle[j];
        shuffle[j] = shuffle[n-i-1];
        
        //
        //  distribute particles evenly to ensure proper spacing
        //
        p[i].x = size*(1.+(k%sx))/(1+sx);
        p[i].y = size*(1.+(k/sx))/(1+sy);

        //
        //  assign random velocities within a bound
        //
        p[i].vx = drand48()*2-1;
        p[i].vy = drand48()*2-1;
    }
    free( shuffle );
}
```

The piece of code I can't understand is here

```
// clear bins at each time step
  for (int m = 0; m < numbins; m++)
bins[m].clear();

  // place particles in bins
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
bins[binNum(particles[i],bpr)].push_back(particles + i);
```

As I understand, the cells of `bins`, are pointers to `particle_t` objects, and not vectors themselves. Unfortunately in the first loop, `bins`'s cells have been treated as vectors themselves, because `.clear()` function has been used on them. In the second loop as well, `bins`'s cells have been treated as vectors themselves by using `.push_back()` on them. Where is the misunderstanding? The code compiles successfully everytime.

Comment: There are almost *never* a reason to have a pointer to a standard container. What should be used for `bins` is a vector of vectors.

Comment: On a similar note, you should almost *never* use `malloc` in C++ code. `particles` should be a vector as well. In fact, whenever you need to do a C-style cast in C++ (like you do for `malloc`) you should take that as a sign you're doing something wrong. If the shown code was given to you from someone else, then that other person needs to go back to school and learn C++ properly.

Comment: *"As I understand, the cells of `bins`, are pointers to `particle_t` objects, and not vectors themselves."* -- not accurate. Think this way: `bins` is a pointer to something, let's call it X. Think abstractly. If X was `int` (meaning you had something like `int *intptr`), then what would you have if you used a subscript on your variable? That is, what would be the type of `intptr[0]`? From that specific case, substitute X for `int` to get back to the abstract, then substitute "vector of pointers" for X to get back to your question's case.

Comment: `bins` is a pointer, but in you case, it points to a dyncamially-allocated array of vectors. As already said, a vector-of-vectors should be used instead.

Comment: (I'd consider answering, but the whole premise of a pointer to a vector is so counter to usual C++ practice, that I find myself questioning the long-term value of having this question-answer in Stack Overflow.)

Comment: @JaMiT thanks for your note, but this is not my code. It's code from a UC Berkeley homework that I have to parallelize.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for your note but I haven't written this code. This is an existing piece of code from a UC Berkeley homework.

Comment: @JaMiT your comment was helpful but can you please explain a little bit more? after all the substitutions you said, I reach a pointer to a vector of pointers and not a vector of vectors.

Comment: If `x` is a `T*`, `x[k]` is a `T`. So, since `bins` is a `vector<particle_t*> *`, `bins[m]` is a `vector<particle_t*>`

Comment: @molbdnilo so many thanks. u did a big favor to me.

Comment: @RezaNamvar I tried to phrase my comment neutrally since it did seem to me like you were given that part of the code. ;) My intent was not to criticize so much as to explain why I opted against a clear explanation in an official answer. (My other comment was intentionally indirect -- unintentionally not clear enough -- since answers in comments should be avoided. Tough to get the balance right sometimes.)